# Jquery Carousel - trying to add custom scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I have tried searching online and browsed the relevant "answered" questions here, but nothing seems to quite fit my problem so I am hoping someone knows the answer to this.

I have a site I am coding http://2938.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/index.html and I have the carousel (carouFredsel) working perfect; however, I would like to add a scrollbar similar to the one used here http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow.

I have the images to make the scroll bar, but am a noob when it comes to Jquery. I did find some information for adding a jquery scroll bar to content div's but they required the divs to be absolute and in order for my carousel to work the way it does, it needs to be relative.

Is what I want to do possible?

I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I tried getting the code to work in JSfiddle but was unsuccessful, so I provided a link to the sandbox instead.

Here is the script inside the header:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {

        $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
            items   : 2,
            auto: {
                duration: 750
                },
            scroll  : {
                items: 1,
                duration: 750,
            onAfter: function() {
  if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
    $(this).trigger( "pause" );
  }
}},
        }).parent().css("margin", "auto");
        });

    </script>
```

And here is the html for the carousel:

```
    <div class="list_carousel">
    <ul id="foo3">
<li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-3.jpg" alt="Testing description" /></li>
<li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-6.jpg" alt="Text_2" /></li>
<li style="width:238px"><img src="Images/SMP-4.jpg" alt="Text_6" /></li>
<li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-2.jpg" alt="Text_3" /></li>
<li style="width:238px"><img src="Images/SMP-5.jpg" alt="new description" /></li>  </ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I believe it is possible with the use of the mousewheel plug-in which is simple enough. However, my original issue was (and still is) how to make the image of the scroll bar show up to use with the mousewheel scroll function. The image(s) consist of the line for the bar and the nav circle which moves along the bar.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't read this image gallery documentation, instead of searching?

http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Documentation

Comment: instead of being dismissive of my question... if you had read my inquiry you would have noticed that the link you posted is for the scroll bar I want to use with a different carousel (the CarouFredsel). The commands would be different, would they not?

Comment: you can use jquery ui slider and customize it, mentioned library has a scroll option, http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/configuration.php, isn't this proper for your image gallery?

Comment: I am using the scroll option, but as I mentioned I am very new to jquery and the site does not explain how to add a scroll bar to their scrolling option. It only provides the configuration for buttons.